# IIF + filter + inst functions in MDX Excel

Tags: excel, filter, mdx, olap, iif

I need to calculate measure if the string contains a specific character. 
I tried the following code:

```
IIF
(FILTER([Client for GPS].[External ID], Instr([Client for GPS].[External ID].CURRENTMEMBER.name,"-",1)),

[Measures].[Calls Count],
NULL)
```

But it shows all `NULL` values as a result

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the IIF and FILTER need to be the other way around:

```
FILTER(
[Client for GPS].[External ID],
IIF(
  INSTR(
       [Client for GPS].[External ID].CURRENTMEMBER.name
       ,"-"
       ,1
   ) > 0
,[Measures].[Calls Count]
,NULL
)
```